# jQuery append always selected item twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have append new form with jQuery, and when I choose one item from dropdown I need to get append bellow it the div/form, but it always append twice. I dont know why! The other jquery element are not adding it, i have checked, I am using it inside of function in jQuery

this is my code

```
function addBrand( brandName )
    {

            jQuery('#example').append('' +
                '<form name="search" action="" method="get" id="search">' +
                '<div class="add_marke parentElement" id="add_marke_'+brandName+'"  > ' +
                '   <div class="car_tag"><span  class="lbl">' +brandName+ '&nbsp' + '&nbsp;<span id="car_name" class="icon-remove car-remove"></span></span></div> ' + '&nbsp' +
                '   <input type="hidden" name="markeName" id="markeName" value="'+brandName+'"></input>'+
                '   <select  name="model_cars" id="model_cars_'+brandName+'" class="search_dropdown_small ">' +
                '       <option id="selectModel" name="selectModel_All" value="all" >Alle </option>' +
                '       <option id="selectModel_Selected" name="selectModel_Selected" value="selected" >Nur gewählte</option>'+
                '       <option id="selectModel_Excluded" name="selectModel_Excluded" value="exclude" >Alle au&#xdf;er</option>' +
                '   </select>'+ '&nbsp' +

                '</div>' +
                '</form>');

 return(this);

    }

    jQuery("#model").change(function(){
        var brandName = jQuery("#model").val();
        jQuery(this).ready(addBrand(brandName));
    });
```

Comment: Only the current document has a `ready` handler, elements do **not**

Comment: remove `return(this);` or simply use `return true`

Comment: I have made a change, but it always shows double, every item that I choose it double it.

Comment: there may be a case that you've attached two handlers for the same event and both are being fired when you're changing the model text!
please create and share a fiddle of the same!

Answer (score 1):

should read like this:

```
function addBrand( brandName )
  {

    jQuery('#example').append('' +
      '<form name="search" action="" method="get" id="search">' +
      '<div class="add_marke parentElement" id="add_marke_'+brandName+'"  > ' +
      '   <div class="car_tag"><span  class="lbl">' +brandName+ '&nbsp' + '&nbsp;<span id="car_name" class="icon-remove car-remove"></span></span></div> ' + '&nbsp' +
      '   <input type="hidden" name="markeName" id="markeName" value="'+brandName+'"></input>'+
      '   <select  name="model_cars" id="model_cars_'+brandName+'" class="search_dropdown_small ">' +
      '       <option id="selectModel" name="selectModel_All" value="all" >Alle </option>' +
      '       <option id="selectModel_Selected" name="selectModel_Selected" value="selected" >Nur gewählte</option>'+
      '       <option id="selectModel_Excluded" name="selectModel_Excluded" value="exclude" >Alle au&#xdf;er</option>' +
      '   </select>'+ '&nbsp' +

      '</div>' +
      '</form>');

    return true;

  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#model").change(function(){
      var brandName = jQuery("#model").val();
      addBrand(brandName);
    });
  });
```

Comment: I have made a change, but it always shows double, every item that I choose it double it.  I dont know what could be wrong

Comment: can you please create and share a fiddle of the same? would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
function addBrand( brandName )
    {

            $('#example').append(
                '<form name="search" action="" method="get" id="search">' +
                '<div class="add_marke parentElement" id="add_marke_'+brandName+'"  > ' +
                '   <div class="car_tag"><span  class="lbl">' +brandName+ '&nbsp' + '&nbsp;<span id="car_name" class="icon-remove car-remove"></span></span></div> ' + '&nbsp' +
                '   <input type="hidden" name="markeName" id="markeName" value="'+brandName+'"></input>'+
                '   <select  name="model_cars" id="model_cars_'+brandName+'" class="search_dropdown_small ">' +
                '       <option id="selectModel" name="selectModel_All" value="all" >Alle </option>' +
                '       <option id="selectModel_Selected" name="selectModel_Selected" value="selected" >Nur gewählte</option>'+
                '       <option id="selectModel_Excluded" name="selectModel_Excluded" value="exclude" >Alle au&#xdf;er</option>' +
                '   </select>'+ '&nbsp' +

                '</div>' +
                '</form>');


    }
 $("#model").change(function(){
    var brandName = $("#model").val();
     addBrand(brandName);
});
```

if you don't want to append then use `.html(` in place of `.append(`

Check **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M9J5P/1/)**

Another **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M9J5P/2/)**